# How to render Google Maps by javaScript Rendering?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, rendering

Is it necessary to use `page.client.register` script for rendering the JavaScript of Google maps?

Or is there any other alternative?

api GOOGLE MAP..ANY CLUE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the map to your page with something like:

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
```

Where did you get `page.client.register` from?